# Why are the protocols not available to me in "other locations" [samba]?

Tags: 22.04, samba

After reinstalling samba, the ability to connect to a network folder via the ui disappeared.

[image]

[image]

Terminal command outputs:

```
-> smbclient -N -L //192.168.0.10 -U guest                                                       

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    ADMIN$          Disk      Удаленный Admin
    C$              Disk      Стандартный общий ресурс
    IPC$            IPC       Удаленный IPC
    Space           Disk      
    Users           Disk      
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
do_connect: Connection to 192.168.0.10 failed (Error NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND)
Unable to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

```
-> smbtree                                                                                          
Password for [WORKGROUP\kiryano8]:
WORKGROUP
        \\AZURECLOUDPC

smbc_opendir: Network dropped connection on reset
```

File /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   server min protocol = NT1
   server max protocol = SMB3   
   min protocol = NT1
   max protocol = SMB3
   client min protocol = NT1
   client max protocol = SMB3
   wins support = yes
   name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
;   logon drive = H:
;   logon script = logon.cmd
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no
;   read only = yes
;   create mask = 0700
;   directory mask = 0700
;   valid users = %S
Domain Logons
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

How to return the ability to connect via the UI to network folders?

Comment: Is the `gvfs-backends` package correctly installed?

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you very much, installing this package fixed everything. I can't solve the problem for a day. Make your comment as an answer so that I mark it with a solution. Thank you very much, installing this package fixed everything. I can't solve the problem for a day. Make your comment as an answer so that I mark it with a solution.